# Reuse JUnit 5 @ArgumentsSource Parameterized test class across different java projects

Tags: java, junit, junit5, parameterized-unit-test

I have below maven java projects:

1. com.validator
2. com.demoModel1
3. com.demoModel2

**Validator** project contains the validation code and the jar is used by **demoModel1** and **demoModel2** projects to perform validation. To perform validation, in demoModel1 and demoModel2 projects, I have to write **JUnit test cases**, but those test cases are similar, except different index for them as parameters. Because of that reason, I have created a parameterized test class named **ExecuteSimulation**:

```
import org.junit.jupiter.api.extension.ExtensionContext;
import org.junit.jupiter.params.provider.Arguments;
import org.junit.jupiter.params.provider.ArgumentsProvider; 
   
public class ExecuteSimulation implements ArgumentsProvider {}
```

For now, I have to create this **ExecuteSimulation** class in both **demoModel1** and **demoModel2** projects. But I want to reuse the **ExecuteSimulation** class in both **demoModel1** and **demoModel2** projects. I tried to put **ExecuteSimulation** class in **com.validator** project. If I put the class in the ***src/java*** folder of **com.validator** project, it yields error, complaining that ***junit dependencies are not found***.

If I put **ExecuteSimulation** class in the ***src/test*** folder of **com.validator** project and try to use it in **demoModel1** and **demoModel2**, both of the project yields errors complaining that the reference of **ExecuteSimulation** class from **com.validator** project is not found. I guess it happens because of the location src/test.

In this regard, what will be the proper way to reuse this parameterized test class across different maven java projects?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're trying to achieve is described in the [Maven JAR plugin documentation ("how to create a jar containing test classes")](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-jar-plugin/examples/create-test-jar.html). You have basically two options:

1. Create a separate `jar` file with the test classes of an existing module (`test-jar` build based on `src/test`).
2. Create a separate module with the classes used across the tests (built based on `src/java` in this module).

Both approaches will yield a `jar` file that should be imported as a dependency in other modules with `test` scope. If you decide to go with the second approach, the dependencies like JUnit will not have a `test` scope in this new module, but they will be used only with this scope in the modules importing them.

Comment: In my case, this will be the 1st point with test-jar.